Unable to create zone redundant Azure SQL Server and App Service Plan in any region
Pretty much the title. I'm unable to create a zone redundant Azure SQL Server and App Service Plan in any region.
Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Here is the output of a test script I wrote. No zones had a successful deployment.
Testing deployment in eastus
Creating SQL Server...
Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database...
ERROR: (ProvisioningDisabled) Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Code: ProvisioningDisabled
Message: Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Failed to create zone-redundant SQL Database in eastus
Deployment failed in eastus
Testing deployment in eastus2
Creating SQL Server...
Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database...
ERROR: (ProvisioningDisabled) Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Code: ProvisioningDisabled
Message: Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Failed to create zone-redundant SQL Database in eastus2
Deployment failed in eastus2
Testing deployment in centralus
Creating SQL Server...
Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database...
Creating Zone-Redundant App Service Plan...
WARNING: Readonly attribute name will be ignored in class <class 'azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.models._models_py3.AppServicePlan'>
ERROR: Operation cannot be completed without additional AZ quota. Please file a support ticket to request a limit increase. 
Additional details - Location: Central US 
Current Limit (PremiumV3 VMs): 0. 
Current Usage: 0. 
Amount required for this deployment (PremiumV3 VMs): 3. 
(Minimum) New Limit that you should request to enable this deployment: 3. 
Note that if you experience multiple scaling operations failing (in addition to this one) and need to accommodate the aggregate quota requirements of these operations, you will need to request a higher quota limit than the one currently displayed.
Failed to create zone-redundant App Service Plan in centralus
Deployment failed in centralus
Testing deployment in southcentralus
Creating SQL Server...
ERROR: (RegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning) Location 'South Central US' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers at this time.
Code: RegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning
Message: Location 'South Central US' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers at this time.
Failed to create SQL Server in southcentralus
Deployment failed in southcentralus
Testing deployment in westus
Creating SQL Server...
Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database...
ERROR: (ProvisioningDisabled) Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Code: ProvisioningDisabled
Message: Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Failed to create zone-redundant SQL Database in westus
Deployment failed in westus
Testing deployment in westus2
Creating SQL Server...
Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database...
ERROR: (ProvisioningDisabled) Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Code: ProvisioningDisabled
Message: Provisioning of zone redundant database/pool is not supported for your current request.
Failed to create zone-redundant SQL Database in westus2
Deployment failed in westus2
Testing deployment in westus3
Creating SQL Server...
ERROR: (RegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning) Location 'West US 3' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers at this time.
Code: RegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning
Message: Location 'West US 3' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers at this time.
Failed to create SQL Server in westus3
Deployment failed in westus3
Deployment Tests Summary:
Successful regions: 
Failed regions: eastus eastus2 centralus southcentralus westus westus2 westus3
Script execution completed.

Here is the script
#!/bin/bash

# Base variables
let "randomIdentifier=$RANDOM*$RANDOM"
IS_PROD=true  # Set to true for production, false for staging

# SQL Variables
ADMIN_LOGIN="azureuser"
ADMIN_PASSWORD="p4ssw0rd-$randomIdentifier"

# Set environment-specific variables
if [ "$IS_PROD" = true ]; then
    SQL_SKU_TIER="Premium"
    SQL_SKU_CAPACITY=125
    ZONE_REDUNDANCY=true
    BACKUP_REDUNDANCY="Geo"
    SKU_NAME="P1V3"
    NUMBER_OF_WORKERS=3
else
    SQL_SKU_TIER="Basic"
    SQL_SKU_CAPACITY=5
    ZONE_REDUNDANCY=false
    BACKUP_REDUNDANCY="Local"
    SKU_NAME="B1"
    NUMBER_OF_WORKERS=1
fi

# List of US regions to test
regions=("eastus" "eastus2" "centralus" "southcentralus" "westus" "westus2" "westus3")

# Function to test deployment
test_deployment() {
    let "randomIdentifier=$RANDOM*$RANDOM"
    local LOCATION=$1
    local RESOURCE_GROUP="test-rg-$randomIdentifier"
    local SQL_SERVER_NAME="dbsvr$randomIdentifier"
    local SQL_DB_NAME="dbname$randomIdentifier"
    local APP_SERVICE_PLAN_NAME="appsvcplan-$randomIdentifier"

    echo "Testing deployment in $LOCATION"

    # Create a resource group
    if ! az group create --name $RESOURCE_GROUP --location $LOCATION > /dev/null; then
        echo "Failed to create resource group in $LOCATION"
        return 1
    fi

    # Create SQL Server
    echo "Creating SQL Server..."
    if ! az sql server create \
      --name $SQL_SERVER_NAME \
      --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
      --location $LOCATION \
      --admin-user $ADMIN_LOGIN \
      --admin-password $ADMIN_PASSWORD > /dev/null; then
        echo "Failed to create SQL Server in $LOCATION"
        az group delete --name $RESOURCE_GROUP --yes --no-wait > /dev/null
        return 1
    fi

    # Create SQL Database
    echo "Creating Zone-Redundant SQL Database..."
    if ! az sql db create \
      --name $SQL_DB_NAME \
      --server $SQL_SERVER_NAME \
      --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
      --edition $SQL_SKU_TIER \
      --capacity $SQL_SKU_CAPACITY \
      --zone-redundant $ZONE_REDUNDANCY \
      --backup-storage-redundancy $BACKUP_REDUNDANCY > /dev/null; then
        echo "Failed to create zone-redundant SQL Database in $LOCATION"
        az group delete --name $RESOURCE_GROUP --yes --no-wait > /dev/null
        return 1
    fi

    # Create App Service Plan
    echo "Creating Zone-Redundant App Service Plan..."
    if ! az appservice plan create \
      --name $APP_SERVICE_PLAN_NAME \
      --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
      --location $LOCATION \
      --sku $SKU_NAME \
      --is-linux \
      --zone-redundant \
      --number-of-workers $NUMBER_OF_WORKERS > /dev/null; then
        echo "Failed to create zone-redundant App Service Plan in $LOCATION"
        az group delete --name $RESOURCE_GROUP --yes --no-wait > /dev/null
        return 1
    fi

    echo "Successfully created all resources in $LOCATION"
    az group delete --name $RESOURCE_GROUP --yes --no-wait > /dev/null
    return 0
}

# Login to Azure
az login

# Test deployment in each region
successful_regions=()
failed_regions=()

for region in "${regions[@]}"; do
    if test_deployment $region; then
        successful_regions+=("$region")
        echo "Deployment successful in $region"
    else
        failed_regions+=("$region")
        echo "Deployment failed in $region"
    fi
done

# Print summary
echo "Deployment Tests Summary:"
echo "Successful regions: ${successful_regions[*]}"
echo "Failed regions: ${failed_regions[*]}"

echo "Script execution completed."

I would expect to be able to deploy this configuration in at least one of the regions.
As far as the quota for P1V3, I did request an increase(three times). The request was closed every time with the following response. I do not know how to continue.
QMS Update - Status: ResourceType: computeCores
 {
    Quota Bucket: standardDDv4Family
    Status Description: This functionality is currently in private preview and only available for select customers. Please resubmit your request under the Technical support path.
    State: OfferCodeNotSupportedForResouceProvider
    Current Quota: 0
    New Quota: 3
}
Properties: [location, centralus]
}


The ProvisioningDisabled error indicates that zone-redundant databases or pools are not supported for your current request in certain regions. This could be due to regional limitations or specific subscription constraints. Have you verified that the type of subscription you are using does not have constraints for that, for example Azure for Students or Azure Free Trial? You told us you have already requested quota increase so maybe there are constraints at the subscription level.
You are also receiving quota limit errors when trying to create Premium V3 VMs. If you are using an Azure subscription that have constraints, the Azure A-series VM give you a better chance of being allowed to create a VM. Free Trial accounts cannot create premium VMs.
The error RegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning suggests that the region is not currently accepting new SQL Database server creations. Some regions may temporarily restrict new resource provisioning due to capacity constraints or maintenance. My students use Azure for Students, and they are usually successful creating resources on India South, UK South, Australia, US Central.
